# MongoDB Journal on Secondary Servers

Tags: mongodb

Does MongoDB store journals in secondary servers too?  I checked the documentation but couldn't find this information anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Journal files are written on all mongod instances, unless disabled. I would not recommend disabling as an unclean shut down without can lead to data corruption.

Answer (score 3):

#### Short answer

Yes, there are journals on the secondaries *by default* and the replication makes use of it.

#### Longer answer

It is implicit that write concern is about data committed to the in memory data, which is synced to the journal every [commitIntervalMs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.journal.commitIntervalMs), if the journal isn't explicitly deactivated. I strongly second @JamesWahlin's advice not to deactivate the journaling unless you have very good reason to do so (for example on an arbiter only instance of mongod).

The in memory data get's synced to the datafiles every [syncPeriodSecs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.syncPeriodSecs).

That behavior is the same regardless wether the data comes from a client or an oplog entry being processed.

The write concern does not modify the behaviour of how the data is written (unless the `fsync` option is set to true). A query will simply return only after the steps configured in the write concern were successfully made.

#### Edit

As Adam commented, the journal isn't diretly used by replication. It is used as a part of normal data processing. There is no dedicated logic of using the journal in the context of a replica set.

However, when the `{j:true}` option is used in the write concern configuration (default, per connection or in the request level), MongoDB divides the commitIntervalMs by three in order to have the query return faster at the expense of (slightly) higher disk IO.

Comment: A couple of comments to clarify: First, replication does not use journaling directly, which seems to be implied by the way you have phrased it, replicated traffic is just a write to the oplog/collection so it goes in the journal like any other. Second, a j:true write concern will have an effect - if there is a j:true write pending the journal will attempt to commit in the `commitIntervalMs` divided by 3 to try to improve responsiveness for such write concerns.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear about that. I will update accordingly to make it more visible.

Comment: @AdamComerford: I thought the division was made on `syncPeriodSecs` for an fsync. Got that one confused. Shame on me, M102 tought me better. ;)